# How can I add routing to entire different(from gw) subnet?

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing

I want to add routing from 10.10.1.100 interface to 169.254.1.0 network. How it's possible to do in Windows 7?

Comment: You are right, I have corrected title.

Comment: While you're at it, the link-local block 169.254.0.0/16 would have been "class B" anyway, not class A. (Though if you use only a /24 subnet, some people would call it "class C" based on its size, ignoring the bit prefix, even though that's how the dead-since-1993 classes were distinguished.)

Comment: But the more important question is, is that network on-link, or is it reachable via a gateway?

Comment: both 10.10.1.100 pc and 169.254.1.0 computers are connected to the same switch, if that was question. 169.254.1.0 has gw 169.254.1.1 as gw. I can't change anything on 169 computers, but can add routing on 10.. computer.

Comment: Yes, that was the question. The thing is, the 169.254.0.0/16 block is "link-local" and therefore [explicitly forbidden from being routed](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3927#section-7). So "same switch" is the only way you _could_ access them. (Also, the fact that those computers even _have_ a gateway configured is already unusual.)

Comment: yes, it's unusual but that's how currently they setup and I am on the way to change it. Now I only need IP access to them, which the answer below failed to solve.

Comment: I'd start from the opposite end of this [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)  - **why** are they getting 169 addresses, not 'how do I route unroutable addresses'

Comment: I don't have access to them now to start from the other end. They are headless live boxes.

Comment: & they cannot see a DHCP server...

Comment: The setup is static IP now. There is program which can modify everything, including DHCP and all, but first I need somehow get access to them. Unfortunately I am also not able/limited changing 10.10.1.100 to 169, because of currently working production applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After alot of comments I am reading the setup as follows:

```
       ------------------    switch  -----------------
      /                  (not a router)                \
      |                     |                          |
      |                     |                          |
Valid PROD hosts      My win 7 computer         Headless boxes
on 10.0.0.0/8         (atm on 10.0.0.0/8)        On 169.254.0.0/16
```

Note that no routers are involved.

> I am also not able/limited changing 10.10.1.100 to 169, because of 
>   currently working production applications.

That leaves a few options.

1. Also add a 169... IP on your windows 7 desktop and to this first time right, so it does not disturb any production items.
2. Get a temporary fourth PC and play around with that. Should be trivial to boot that, set up a static IP in 169... You now can reach the headless boxes (even though they do not yet communicate with  the other PROD hosts. But you can configure them and fix them so they are also in 10.0.0.0/8...)
3. Note that is the headless boxes are local then you could also grab a semi random laptop/desktop, only connect these headless boxes and the laptop to an independant switch. Then properly configure them and only then connect them to the production network.

Now if the setup is less simple and it is not a switch, but there are one or more routers in between then you may have a problem.  RFC1918 IPs are not supposed to be routable. Thus if there are any router in between you will need to reconfigure them. If there are third party routers (e,g, the headless boxes are in another office and you try to reach them via the Internet) then give up. Try something different. (e.g. first VPN to a box in that office, or log into the router in the other office).

If this is the case, then please add more detail to the original post.

Comment: This is very close to what I have here. Actually I just went with N.1 solution. 2 involves more efforts, 3 - complicated, because more than 100 boxes involved). So thanks for answer with complete options.

Answer (score 2):

You need a router between those two networks. In route command gateway must be in same subnet that peer ip address. So router must have, at least, two addresses. For instance 10.10.1.1 and 169.254.1.0.

A workaroud can be, if both networks are connected to the same physical ethernet network, add a second ip address to your computer in the second ip subnet. But doing so makes you unable to use DHCP; all IP addresses must be fixed.

Comment: You can work around that add the other IP to a second (or third or fouth...) network card.  Leaving the first on DHCP and setting the second to a static IP.

Comment: This solution works

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using route add in cmd.exe.

EXAMPLE:

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.10.0.1  
route add "Source_network" mask "Subnetmask" "Destination_gateway"
```

Note:

The route will be deleted after the machine is rebooted. In order for the route to stay use the -p flag to make it persistent.

```
route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.10.0.1  -P
```

Comment: `route add 169.254.1.0 mask 255.255.255.255 10.10.1.100 -p` or `route add 169.254.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 10.10.1.100 -p` didn't give access to 169.254.1.* computers.

Answer (score 0):

"169.254.1.0" by itself is not a network. Usually 169.254.0.0/16 is used for link-local addresses, though according to your comments, your network uses 169.254.1.0/24.

You say that these hosts are on the same link (connected to the same switch). Which is good, since the 169.254.0.0/16 range is defined as "link-local" and explicitly forbidden from being routed. (Some routers allow this, but most will refuse to forward packets from/to this network.)

On-link means you should add a route *without* a gateway, but directly with a destination interface.

- In Windows 7 syntax, that would be:

  ```
  netsh interface ipv4 add route 169.254.1.0/24 "Local Area Connection"
  ```
- Using `route`:

  ```
  route add  169.254.1.0  mask 255.255.255.0  0.0.0.0  if <ifindex>
  ```

  Note that you must first replace `<ifindex>` with the *real* interface ID (e.g. 16), which is shown at the top of `route print`, like such:

  ```
  Interface List
   16...00 15 5d 21 cf 04 ......Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
    1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1�
  ```

Comment: `route add 169.254.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 if 13 -P` didn't work unfortunately... IF 13 is pointing to correct adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to have a gateway outside your subnet - Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 have the powershell cmdlets to enable direct access outside the subnet, the "Get-NetOffloadGlobalSetting" shows the current state, and "Set-NetOffloadGlobalSetting -NetworkDirectAcrossIPSubnets" allows you to configure the value. Althought PowerShell understands the syntax of the "NetworkDirectAcrossIPSubnets" on client operating systems, this feature is available for servers only, setting it under a client OS will give an error.